# Java / Spring / JSP - how to output value added using ModelAndView.addObject

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have the following code in my controller

```
final ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView();
m.addObject("date", "15" );
```

In my view I have been able to output this by doing

```
${date}
```

However how can I print it out using out.print or assign it to a new variable
e.g.

```
<% out.print( ${date} ) %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From within your jsp page, you can retrieve the value of `date` with:

```
<%
Integer myDate = (Integer) request.getAttribute("date");
out.println(myDate);
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a little JSTL help to set the variable to the page scope.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

...

<c:set var="date" value="${date}"/>
<% 
    String date = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("date");
    out.println(date); 
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, it's:

```
(Integer)pageContext.getAttribute("date")
```

so it will be:

```
<% out.println((Integer)pageContext.getAttribute("date")); %>
```

in your code.